xarray/dask wait drive I/O before continuing processing
The pseudocode looks as follows:
def obtain_chunk(da):
    c = download_chunk()
    c = process_stuff(c)
    return c

# lazy dask array wrapped into xarray with many chunks
da = xr.DataArray(dask.array...)

# obtain each chunk with dask distributed
da.map_blocks(obtain_chunk)

# save as zarr file
da.to_zarr()

This works all fine as long as the drive the result it saved to is fast enough. If the network/processing from which the dask array is filled is faster than the hard drive, then memory fills up slowly and the process crashes at some point. I.e. dask continues to process and download chunks while the drive cannot keep up saving the data.
fwiw: currently writing this: https://github.com/cmosig/sentle, where I am facing this issue.

This should not append considering https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/scheduling-policies.html#avoid-over-saturating-workers. But it depends on your settings. Dask shouldn't load more chunks in memory than the number of active threads * 1.1.
